# gcc complaining "multiple definition of 'funname' ", then how to declare a global character array?

Tags: c, gcc, static, global, extern

I have a header **error.h**, and this is where I want to declare my global character array `funname`.

My idea is to declare `funname` in **error.h**, and include this header in all of my `*.c` files. `funname` stores the function name in which the latest error occured (in-built error + my own defined errors). Every function which has a potential to generate error assigns its name to `funname` like this:

```
//filename: someSourcecode.c

#include "error.h"

int fun1(int a, float b)
{
    strcpy(funname, "fun1");

    if(someUnexpectedEvent)
    {
        errno = MyOwnDefinedMacroWithIntegerValue;
        return -2;
    }
}
```

I also have **error.c** file which prints error messages for their respective `eerno`. `printerror` is the function in **error.c** which prints those error messages and that function is defined like this:

```
//filename: error.c

#include "error.h"

void printerror()
{
    if(errno == USERUNAVAILABLE)  //own defined errno value
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error:  %s   user is unavailable\n", funname);
    }

    ... //and so on
}
```

### My Problem:

in `error.h` file, if I declare it like this (globally)-
`char funname[1024] = "";` , my invidual `*.c` compiles (each `*.c` file is compiled with command `gcc -c file1.c`) compiled without any error **but** when I tried to link them all at once (`gcc file1.o file2.o file3.o file4.o main.o -o bin`), it showed error like this:

```
/usr/bin/ld: bin/file1.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `originFuncName'; bin/main.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: bin/file2.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `originFuncName'; bin/main.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: bin/error.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `originFuncName'; bin/main.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: bin/file3.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `originFuncName'; bin/main.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: bin/file4.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `originFuncName'; bin/main.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
```

And if I declare like this (globally)- `static char funname[1024] = "";`, then I don't have any problem in compiling and linking, it also runs properly, **except, when error message is print, the function name is not printed**, probably printing **null string** as function name.

What should I do?

Comment: this is generally obtained with preprocessing macros.

Answer (score 1):

This declaration

```
char funname[1024] = "";
```

also is a definition of the variable `funname`. Thus if the header is included in several translation units then you will have multiple definitions of the same variable.

You should declare the variable in the header like for example

```
extern char funname[1024];
```

and then define it in some module like

```
char funname[1024] = "";
```

As for this declaration

```
static char funname[1024] = "";
```

then the variable `funname` has internal linkage. It means that every translation unit where the header is included will have its own separate variable.